# Upgrading ImageResizer from 3.4.3 to 4.0 seems to break S3Reader

Tags: amazon-s3, imageresizer

We've been evaluating ImageResizer, and so far, so good. One of our main use cases is images that have been uploaded to S3, and we wanted to test the rewritten S3 plugin in 4.0. From an app with a working installation of 3.4.3:

- Downloaded the NuGet packages [from AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/imazen/resizer/build/4.0.0.788/artifacts).
- Used a local package source to upgrade the app's dependencies, and remove the obsolete Mvc package.
- Removed the `MvcRoutingShim`, but made no other changes to `web.config`.

After rebuilding the app, things generally seem to work (testing on my workstation, with VS2012 and IIS Express 8). I can fetch images through the `RemoteReader` plugin. A simple URL-rewriting plugin we wrote seems to work fine. But I can't get the `S3Reader2` plugin to yield anything but 404s. I've fiddled with a number of the plugin settings, and tried various combinations of good and bad URLs with no success.

Here's [a Gist with the diagnostics output](https://gist.github.com/sixten/483694deaa53797e4c75).

Is there some change to the config that needs to be made upgrading to 4.0? Some reason why it won't work running locally? A more stable build of 4.0 that I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be fixed when using the newer [4.0.0-prerelease0877 packages](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/4.0.0-prerelease0877) from NuGet. I speculate that we might have been seeing [issue #139](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/issues/139), but we'll probably never know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the diagnostics page, it appears that you do not have a static file handler or module installed. Since you're using DiskCache, ImageResizer delegates the serving of disk cached files to whatever static file server is configured, so that you can get optimal performance and support for all the esoteric HTTP commands.

Adding a static file handler should solve this.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

You should also verify that the native static file module is installed (it is faster, in theory).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2196177?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Hmm. But it worked with 3.4.3, and works now with RemoteReader. Disabling the disk cache doesn't correct the problem, either.

Comment: Nor did adding that handler in fix it. Is there some way to get more information out of the S3 plugin about what it's trying to do & where its failing? Do I need to install your logging plugin (…and NLog)?

Comment: Try [build 793](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/imazen/resizer/build/artifacts). It's possible that the 404 is actually a missing dependency. Newer builds unmask the underlying problem (in theory).

Comment: I've updated to 793, and I see the same 404 for S3. I'm pretty sure [the change](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/commit/b18e76690302786d96db2e2cc856b44352d47621) you're referring to was already in 788, which I'd been using. Again, is there some way that I can get more detailed output about the failure from your code?

Comment: It's more about figuring out why the request isn't reaching ImageResizer. Attaching a debugger is one relatively simple way. There are also many kinds of 404s. 

Does the S3ReaderSample from the project's Samples folder work on your configuration of IIS?

Comment: Given that it works with the stable version, and with other plugins, I'm not convinced that it _isn't_ reaching ImageResizer. I'll take a look at the sample, though.

Comment: It could very well be a bug in ImageResizer; at this point v4 can't even be called alpha yet, it's more  like a technical preview. Either way I want to fix it, but I need to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: And I really want to be able to provide more information about what's wrong, so that you can reproduce. But there doesn't seem to be much more diagnostic info to provide. Just noticed that "Currently, detailed logging has only been implemented for the DiskCache plugin," so I guess the logging plugin isn't going to help here.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a new clean project? If so, that's somewhere to start.

Comment: Interesting. I was kind of checking in on the status of v4, and this caught my eye: https://github.com/imazen/resizer/issues/139. Any idea whether that's the issue I was running into here?

Comment: Quite possibly; try the v4 version on nuget.org